# Personalizacão de uma função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Além de Width, Height e Resizable, quais outros atributos podem ser inseridos numa função?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: _"quais outros atributos podem ser inseridos numa função"_ - numa função geral ou nesse `.dialog` especifico?

Comment: Nesse .dialog em específico

Comment: Esse dialog é [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), jQuery ou outro?

Comment: A função é em JavaScript e uso num div em html, acredito que não tenha bootstrap

Comment: Pode ser do jQuery também (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Podes mostrar o HTML desse dialog se não dá para perceber pelos ficheiros que estás a carregar.

Comment: Utilizei uma função para bloquear o botão de voltar do navegador e uso esse .dialog num div informando ao usuário que o botão está bloqueado e como é feito o login do mesmo, é apenas um site para o colégio, nada muito sério.

'<div id="dialog-confirm" valign="center" title="IFHelp"> 
   O Botão de voltar do navegador encontra-se desabilitado. <br />
   Seu login é minúsculo com nome e último sobrenome juntos, ex.: joaosilva
  </div>'

Comment: É dificil responder sem saber a certeza qual o `dialog` que estás a usar. Se for o do jQuery UI as opções são estas: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: É esse mesmo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumindo estares a usar o `.dialog` do jQuery podes encontrar as opções na documentação aqui ([link <sup>em Inglês</sup>](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)).

Basicamente:

```
appendTo  
autoOpen  
buttons  
classes  
closeOnEscape  
closeText  
dialogClass  
draggable  
height  
hide  
maxHeight  
maxWidth  
minHeight  
minWidth  
modal  
position  
resizable  
show  
title  
width
```